# Are there any algorithms capable of finding a tree for a graph taking into account more that one variable?

Tags: algorithm, networking, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I've been given a problem that asks for a minimum tree and optimal tree for a graph, but along with edge cost we're also given a maximum traffic value as well as a traffic value for each node but the first one. I'm aware of Prism's and Kruskal's algorithms, but they don't take into account a second parameter, I tried but failed to find an algorithm able to account for both.

As I understand, the traffic parameter is there to invalidate trees, for example, for the following [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TutgH.jpg) we have all edge weights as well as the traffic for all but first node.

Using Kruskal or Prism we can find that the MST (minimum spanning tree) is the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck2pE.jpg) . However, is we account for the maximum allowed traffic, which in this case is 11, and we determine the traffic for a given route in this tree to be the sum of all the traffics between the origin node and the destination node, we find that the route from node 1 to node 5 has nodes 1, 3, 4 and 5, while we know that T3, T4 and T5 have a traffic of 6, 4 and 2 respectively, and they add up to 12, which would surpass the maximum traffic and invalidate the mst for this case, the question is if there are any algorithms that take two variables into account at once.

Comment: The algorithm's name is Prim. The maximum traffic is the maximum distance between any pair of nodes? Each edge has a weight (distance) and a traffic?

Comment: as far as I know, there are no Prism derivatives that take into account a second variable (in this case traffic) when making the minimum spanning tree.
I think the maximum traffic applies to the traffic from or to node 1 to any other node,  edges have weight but nodes have traffic (except node 1 which is the basis for the tree).

Comment: Both Prim and Kruskal can take as many variables as you only want, the only conditon is to be able to compare edges based on those variables. In your case it's not just another variable. You're basically discarding some valid (under normal circumstances) spanning trees. If I'm correct, your new set of valid spanning trees  does not satisfy matroid conditions, so greedy approach is wrong (in other words, you can't use any common MST algorithm). It looks to me like it's some sort of NP problem. I do not know any algorithms solving it in polynomial time.